# Authorization error Google Drive Android

Tags: android, authorization, google-drive-api

I am trying to import Google Drive into my Android project. I have copied a SHA1 key from debug.keystore and I am using the same package name. For the Activity I used the quickstart code from Google Drive (https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java)

I keep getting following errors (myemail@gmail.com is owner of the application name => Applicationi => Permissions) :

```
    W/GLSActivity(12741): [anc] Status from wire: INVALID_CLIENT_ID status: null

    I/GLSUser(12741): GLS error: INVALID_CLIENT_ID myemail@gmail.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

    E/ClientConnectionOperation(21217): Handling authorization failure

    E/ClientConnectionOperation(21217): boq: Authorization failed: See https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth for details on authorizing an application.
```

Here's my manifest :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.drivequickstart.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to set consent screen (API's & Auth)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know what was meant by the consent screen at first. It is on the Google console and is the next option shown below credentials. Hope this helps if anyone else didn't know where/what this is.

Comment: If you come back, please check out new answer of mine.

Comment: I already had it figured out, but thank you for the link anyway. I appreciate the gesture

Answer (score 0):

I had this, I did everything right but still failed. Finally I created a new 
Project in Google Developers Console. In there I created everything again.

Comment: I had new answer for you, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you setup is DONE. Now, you just need to add Consent screen on you Google Console Developer. Please go to https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#userconsent to finish this one.